# remove root owned file without terminal access

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I recently tried to create an acpi event that is apparently causing problems. I can boot and login, but terminal doesnt load properly (only have an outline, but no prompt). The acpi event `/etc/acpi/my_event` apparently has root permissions so I cant delete it through the GUI. I also tried booting into the startup repair shell but it only has read access. How can I remove this file?

Comment: booting into a *live* version of *linux* is not an option?

Comment: If you're on a physical linux system, try CTRL-ALT-F1 (or F up to 6), you'll enter in a virtual console provided by getty/agetty

Comment: @fedterzi, that worked perfectly thanks